# Create a new Server 2012 domain user with access to local user apps

Tags: windows-server-2012

As the title states, I would like to create a new Windows 2012 user on let the user login to his box using the domain credentials but use the apps that are installed in his local user account. Is this even possible?

Comment: One option is to migrate the profile using the Profile Wizard from ForensiT (http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html). The free version should be fine for a few machines, larger migrations benefit from the paid versions.

Comment: I will check that out, I appreciate the response